# No output and no errors from Voce program

Tags: java, c++, qt, voice, voice-recognition

I am using **[voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/)** voice recognition API which is built for Java and C++. And below is my code

```
#include "C:/Users/yohan/Documents/voce-0.9.1/src/c++/voce.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    voce::init("C:/Users/yohan/Documents/voce-0.9.1/lib", true, false, "", "");

    voce::synthesize("This is a speech synthesis test.");
    voce::synthesize("Type a message to hear it spoken aloud.");

    std::cout << "This is a speech synthesis test.  "
        << "Type a message to hear it spoken aloud." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Type 's' + 'enter' to make the "
        << "synthesizer stop speaking.  Type 'q' + 'enter' to quit."
        << std::endl;

    std::string s;

    while (s != "q")
    {
        // Read a line from keyboard.
        std::getline(std::cin, s);

        if ("s" == s)
        {
            voce::stopSynthesizing();
        }
        else
        {
            // Speak what was typed.
            voce::synthesize(s);
        }
    }

    voce::destroy();
   // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get nothing. No errors, no output, just the console window opening and saying "press return to exit" and that is all. Following is the message got printed in QT console

```
Starting C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\Tired-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_beta2_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Release\release\Tired.exe...
C:\Users\yohan\Documents\QTPeojects\Tired-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_beta2_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Release\release\Tired.exe exited with code 0
```

The **voce.h** is an API file, you can have it from here. This header file uses Jni, to convert Java code to C++. http://sourceforge.net/p/voce/code/HEAD/tree/src/c++/

Comment: Do you need to call setRecognizerEnabled? Also, try making a call to isSynthesizing just after you call voce::synthesize and see if it returns true. Finally, being a console app I'd suggest running from the command line, rather than launching from within the IDE that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in a debugger.  The first line in your main is probably failing and just calls exit(0) when it does.  Put a debug statement above it, too.

Good luck.  Hope that helps.

EDIT: Also be sure to do any appropriate error checking for library calls.  Sometimes this requires a `try` `catch` block, or other times, just checking the return value from function calls.